# Control the tab stop order for code snippet of VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

For example, with following code, when I type "im" and tab, I will get "import {  } from ''", and the initial focus will be at $2 postion, not $1 postion. How can I have the initial focus at $1? Thanks.

```
{
    "import": {
        "prefix": "im",
        "body": [
            "import { $2 } from '$1'"
        ],
        "description": "import element from a module"
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why it is not following the tab stop order, maybe a [bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6250)? 
A workaround could be to explicitly set $0 as end of your tab stop

```
"import": {
    "prefix": "im",
    "body": [
        "import { $0 } from '$1'"
    ],
    "description": "import element from a module"
}
```

vscode [Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userdefinedsnippets):

> The snippet syntax follows the TextMate snippet syntax with the
>   exception of 'regular expression replacements', 'interpolated shell
>   code' and 'transformations', which are not supported.

TextMate snippet syntax [Manual](https://manual.macromates.com/en/snippets#tab_stops):

> The caret will start at $1, then when pressing tab it will move to $2
>   and $3 on next tab etc. until there are no more tab stops. If you do
>   not explicitly set $0, the caret will be at the end of the snippet.